# Two condition Index match in python

Tags: indexing, match

I am currently using excel, but my data file has gotten too large, so I am having issues calculating the value.

I am currently using an index match function in excel to verify two conditions match (B1 & A2,C1 & A3, etc , if so, they return a value (Qty) from a table in cell (B2, C3, etc).  If not, the cell is left blank.B2 & A2

[Table that needs populating](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UHWdD.png)

[Table containing returned value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ecSx.png)